# How can we hide BottomAppBar (with navigation include) when navigate to composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem.

The problem is that i don't know how to hide bottom app bar when i'm navigating to a "add question" screen.

I need your help please.

This is MyScreen with the bottom app bar

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val items = listOf(Screen.Home, Screen.Search, Screen.Notifications, Screen.Profil)

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            bottomAppNavigation(navController = navController, items)

        }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
            ScreenController(navController = navController)
        }

    }
}
```

And this is My controller with navHost

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun ScreenController(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Home.route) {
        composable(Screen.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(Screen.Search.route) {
            SearchScreen(navController, it)
        }
        composable(Screen.Notifications.route) {

        }
        composable(Screen.Profil.route) {
            user_profil()
        }
        composable("Ask_question") {
            AskScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem i think it's because that's like activity and fragment, i have a box where the composable screen goes, and  all my pages are in him.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend you use `AnimatedVisibility` for `BottomNavigation` widget, im my opinion it's clearest way for compose.

1. You should use `remeberSaveable` to store state of BottomBar:

```
// State of bottomBar, set state to false, if current page route is "car_details"
val bottomBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }
```

2. In composable function we used `when` for control state of BottomBar, below we set `bottomBarState` to `true`, if we would like to show BottomBar, otherwise we set `bottomBarState` to `false`:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

// Subscribe to navBackStackEntry, required to get current route
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

// Control BottomBar
when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
    "cars" -> {
        // Show BottomBar
        bottomBarState.value = true
    }
    "bikes" -> {
        // Show BottomBar
        bottomBarState.value = true
    }
    "settings" -> {
        // Show BottomBar
        bottomBarState.value = true
    }
    "car_details" -> {
        // Hide BottomBar
        bottomBarState.value = false
    }
}

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomBar(
            navController = navController,
            bottomBarState = bottomBarState
        )
    },
    content = {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationItem.Cars.route,
        ) {
            composable(NavigationItem.Cars.route) {
                CarsScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                )
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.Bikes.route) {
                BikesScreen(
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.Settings.route) {
                SettingsScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                )
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.CarDetails.route) {
                CarDetailsScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

3. Put `BottomNavigation` inside `AnimatedVisibility`, set `visible` value from `bottomBarState` and set `enter` and `exit` animation, in my case I use `slideInVertically` for `enter` animation and `slideOutVertically` for `exit` animation:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = bottomBarState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
        content = {
            BottomNavigation {
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

                items.forEach { item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                                contentDescription = item.title
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                        selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Full code of MainActivity:

```
package codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi
import androidx.compose.animation.slideInVertically
import androidx.compose.animation.slideOutVertically
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph.Companion.findStartDestination
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.BikesScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.CarDetailsScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.CarsScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.SettingsScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.ui.theme.BottomBarAnimationTheme

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BottomBarAnimationApp()
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun BottomBarAnimationApp() {

    // State of bottomBar, set state to false, if current page route is "car_details"
    val bottomBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }

    BottomBarAnimationTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        // Subscribe to navBackStackEntry, required to get current route
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

        // Control BottomBar
        when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
            "cars" -> {
                // Show BottomBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
            }
            "bikes" -> {
                // Show BottomBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
            }
            "settings" -> {
                // Show BottomBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
            }
            "car_details" -> {
                // Hide BottomBar
                bottomBarState.value = false
            }
        }

        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                BottomBar(
                    navController = navController,
                    bottomBarState = bottomBarState
                )
            },
            content = {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = NavigationItem.Cars.route,
                ) {
                    composable(NavigationItem.Cars.route) {
                        CarsScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                        )
                    }
                    composable(NavigationItem.Bikes.route) {
                        BikesScreen(
                            navController = navController
                        )
                    }
                    composable(NavigationItem.Settings.route) {
                        SettingsScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                        )
                    }
                    composable(NavigationItem.CarDetails.route) {
                        CarDetailsScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavController, bottomBarState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val items = listOf(
        NavigationItem.Cars,
        NavigationItem.Bikes,
        NavigationItem.Settings
    )

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = bottomBarState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
        content = {
            BottomNavigation {
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

                items.forEach { item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                                contentDescription = item.title
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                        selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Result:

[image: BottomBar animation]

Don't forget to use `@ExperimentalAnimationApi` annotation for compose functions.

**Update:** with Compose version 1.1.0 and above `@ExperimentalAnimationApi` not required.

**22.02.2022 Update:** I made some research, and update point 2. Now we use `when` for control `bottomBarState`.

Full code available on gitHub:
https://github.com/AndreiRoze/BottomBarAnimation

Examples of animations available in the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers

Comment: That's nice. I've tried to implement it similarly (DisposableEffect with OnDestinationChangedListener) but the BottomBar simply doesn't animate. Any ideas?

Comment: @bompf are you tried to change BottomBarState value inside OnDestinationChangedListener?

Comment: My mistake. I had wrapped the AnimatedVisibility with `if (isVisible) ...`. Now it works.

Comment: @AndreiR, according to your solution you are passing navController to every composable that might be used to navigate to other composables. Wouldn't that create a messy situation if the car screen has a lot more buttons and clickable composables? In a case like that the composables might be separated into separate folders and packages. And passing navController to every single one of them will surely create a mess, right?

Comment: @FahimHoque, in my case i use simple way of navigation. About complicated cases - you right. If you have a lot of routes, i reccomend to read this article about navigation https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/navigating-in-jetpack-compose-78c78d365c6a. In the end of article you can read different solutions for organise navigation.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to hide the `BottomBar` just don't output it.

Something like:

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        if (currentRoute != "xxxx") {
            BottomAppBar() {
               //....
            }
        }
    },
```

where the `currentRoute` is (using at least Navigation Compose 2.4.0-alpha01):

```
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry.destination.route
```

Comment: oh... Okay, but what is currentRoute ? Because i've made this : val currentRoute = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString(KEY_ROUTE), and it didn't worked

Comment: @Mehdi.ncb I have updated the answer. Check also the official doc: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav

Comment: you answered it but, is that the best way to do this ? Like, when i'm going back, i'm seeing my bottomNavBar appearing from the bottom (Little animation - 0.2s).
So, do you have a best alternative for this ?

Comment: @Mehdi.ncb To be honest I don't know if there is a better alternative but I think that with the current API it is a right way.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, you'r helping a lot of people on stackOverflow

Comment: It a little bit strange, I try using this code but it only run once. When I navigate to another screen currentroute value doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

```
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route in bottomNavItemsList.map { it.route }
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        if (currentDestination) {
            //show
        }
    }
) { innerPaddingModifier ->
    //TODO
}
```