# Collapse Navigation BottomBar while scrolling on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking forward to a way to implement a Collapsing effect while scrolling on `LazyColumn` list. I have been checking the docs but I didn't found nothing related. How can I implement it?

At the moment I'm using a `BottomNavigation` setted inside my `Scaffold` and I can add the inner paddings to the screen coming from the scaffold content lambda. But I didn't find any kind of scrollable state or something close to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [**`nestedScroll`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)) modifier.

Something like:

```
val bottomBarHeight = 48.dp
val bottomBarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { bottomBarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
val bottomBarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }


// connection to the nested scroll system and listen to the scroll
// happening inside child LazyColumn
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {

            val delta = available.y
            val newOffset = bottomBarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
            bottomBarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-bottomBarHeightPx, 0f)

            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

and then apply the `nestedScroll` to the Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
    Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    //..
    bottomBar = {
        BottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier
            .height(bottomBarHeight)
            .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = -bottomBarOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) }) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Localized description")
            }
        }
    },

    content = { innerPadding ->
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = innerPadding) {
            items(count = 100) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(colors[it % colors.size])
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @gabriele-mariotti ! It works.

Which would be the right approach to implement it? Atm I have my bottom bar in the Global/App Scafold like drawers and so. So to implement this I should have a check based on which screen am I to know if include this or not.

Should I include BottomBar individually per screen and add this case when needed, or "Compose-Thinking" it's better to keep it on the upper level?

Comment: I would use the navigation approach. Using the Scaffold in the upper level and just including the BottomBar only where you want. Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575664/how-can-we-hide-bottomappbar-with-navigation-include-when-navigate-to-composab/67576032#67576032

Comment: Gonna try this approach then! However, Doesnt it have some spaggetty code potential starting to put multiple `if` conditions for these cases? Just asking, I'm not that used to think in compose. 
I'm a bit scare that this would lead on a refactor in the future.

If I want the collapsing effect in some screens and others not I end up needing to make an `if ` regarding the route to show the bottom bar, to add the `scrollConnection modifier` and also to modify the `InnerPadding` modifier for the extra padding on the bottom.

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: I tried for the TopAppBar, the problem is the topAppBar does collapse as expected but a white space is left in its place, Is there a different approach recommended for topAppBars?

Comment: Just wanted to note, I've had issues with this solution, but specifically when the list is too short to actually scroll and only on newer OS version. IE: where a an API 28 device will smoothly collapse, but an API 32 device will continuously stop short once the "bounciness" or "stretch" animations start happening since you've reached the end of the list.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Perhaps you know how to fix my issue, could you take a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326733/collapsingtoolbar-in-compose-with-button-sticky

Comment: This is just an animation, i tested with Material design 3, it got a animation move to bottom of screen , then until bottom navigation bar hide almost the list will expand , like bounce, items in old position will jump to below a little bit